# Rails - How to run Helpy application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, server

I am trying to run a cloned `Helpy` application from https://github.com/helpyio/helpy on my local system. `Docker` and `docker-compose` installation has been done.

If I run `rails s` then it will shows `Could not find proper version of railties (4.2.10) in any of the sources
Run`bundle install`to install missing gems.`

If I run `bundle install` then it will shows `An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that "gem install pg -v '0.18.4'" succeeds before bundling.`

Now how can I run this application? Please help me.

Also let me know if any configuration file changes is required as per my localhost or any other installation is required?

Comment: Do you have postgresql installed?

Comment: Just as the error message says, _"Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling"_

Comment: Yes. If I run `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` then also it shows an error like `Error installing pg:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`